# Change complication color dynamically? (Wear OS Jetpack Watch Face API)

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api, watchface, android-wear-complication

How do I change the complication icon color dynamically in the renderer class?

I can set the color and other styles while creating the watchface in the createComplicationSlotsManager inside the canvasComplicationFactory, but after that if the user picks a color or any other setting (using the userStyle) it does not apply to the complications even though I create my complicationDrawable using the data from the userStyle...

Comment: Please share your code that you currently have. It will make it easier for us to suggest solutions.